# Is the official type definition for JSON.stringify wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, types, undefined

I see in [the official type definition for JSON.stringify](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e99c93592701c08f96090c7d4278129b56bc73c6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1119-L1141) that it always returns a string, even when being passed undefined

```
interface JSON {
  stringify(value: any, /*...*/): undefined;
}
```

However `JSON.stringify(undefined)` is `undefined` and therefore not a string

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(undefined))
```

as confirmed by [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#return_value)

So, the official type def seems wrong. What can I do about it?

Comment: FWIW, MDN is a reference, not the spec.

Comment: when a function doesn't return anything, the value is undefined

Comment: The spec is clear about it to tho: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-json.stringify

Comment: You could report it to the Typescript developers.  It appears in `lib.es5.d.ts`

Comment: Why? It would be SO ANNOYING if it returned `string | undefined`. They could add an overload specifically for `undefined` but then when would you use that?

Comment: You posted a link to the GitHub repo... Maybe add an issue to that repo?

Comment: @AlexanderNied but that page does have a link to the official specification

Comment: @caTS  To catch any strange errors maybe,  ?

Comment: Here is an similar issue on this topic: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43639

Comment: See [JSON.stringify should have type string | undefined
#51431](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18879). The issue is from 2017, but I can see [Fix JSON.stringify return type (#18879)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50242) pull request from August 2022 (with an overload)

Comment: lots of people addressed this in the comment.. I'll add my two cents: https://evanhahn.com/when-stringify-doesnt-return-a-string/ yes it's true the _TypeScript’s official definitions for JSON.stringify are incorrect here_.

Comment: `string | undefined` is not ideal.  A simple generic would solve this, eg. simplified example -> `stringify<T>(value:T):(T extends undefined ? undefined : string)`

Answer (score 1):

The return type been `string` is obviously wrong.

Typescript Generics will solve this problem, back in 2017 this might not have been the case.  So if you do contact TS devs to see if this can be updated this is how it can be done now.

```
type JSONReturnType<T> = 
    T extends undefined ? undefined :
    T extends bigint ? undefined :
    T extends Symbol ? undefined :
    string;

interface JSON {
    /**
     * Converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an object.
     * @param text A valid JSON string.
     * @param reviver A function that transforms the results. This function is called for each member of the object.
     * If a member contains nested objects, the nested objects are transformed before the parent object is.
     */
    parse(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any): any;
    /**
     * Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.
     * @param value A JavaScript value, usually an object or array, to be converted.
     * @param replacer A function that transforms the results.
     * @param space Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.
     */
    stringify<T>(value: T, replacer?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): JSONReturnType<T>;
    /**
     * Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.
     * @param value A JavaScript value, usually an object or array, to be converted.
     * @param replacer An array of strings and numbers that acts as an approved list for selecting the object properties that will be stringified.
     * @param space Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.
     */
    stringify<T>(value: T, replacer?: (number | string)[] | null, space?: string | number): JSONReturnType<T>;
}

/**
 * An intrinsic object that provides functions to convert JavaScript values to and from the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.
 */
declare var JSON: JSON;

const a = JSON.stringify({});              //=string
const b = JSON.stringify(undefined);       //=undefined
const c = JSON.stringify(Symbol(''));      //=undefined
const d = JSON.stringify(BigInt('10000')); //=undefined
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHICULAK4CcB2AVcCAHjwD4oBeKAWACgoGo8oIAPYCHAEwGcoNuEAGYBLHBC5QA-P0GjxkgFx1GTFu068oAIxEBzMcGmyuwsRKjL6jZmw7c+cEAFttAewA2xgafkWrqjzAWGJ6ANx0dIYQWEIAhgDG0PDIUADeKowA9ABUOZmMOVAAwm44AG4xwHxxsHHlcXAJIWBGCNoAVhAJRkhuwHHAImVQABQpSACUUEEhOHpQhm5QcThQbp3dwAB0BQxFAAJgcVhxzlAc7FAAglANHiKSEzPBobvWhVBHJ2dQWBDlESVLA3KBCAQ9YZrYAAC0GF1OOB4QjcWGcfFh0H+PAwHmq2yYMJEfHBOEhI2JUAScQ8HgsKJBEESMKgzggrhi6yEFxh0A2XR671UUCKAElubU2RyQQkygMxHxxEELPytjwADQ86BKjiSVU9Gr-BGrZGotmSbTCVHQTFQY7-HBGfVGYlC1Q5LJ7e08CCjS7ARQvOZ6TX-QHAqSBv1EniB1YgTUAawgIEDs1CmvuGAgcZwIGmFHI8cmuZAEQ+UFy+QrIpKZWB1RWdQaTRaRizNuWtRg9UazRErSg7QFvX6gyhYwm03T8zdn2+p3OHdBPZb-cHHc1GBxNI8IBWa2d6xBJ1OCYuy0tVPrVQkc-2X3tv3+YA8iU5t1J5OhcKMwRNDLolqfwQDieI8PetYLr8PDHEkNxcFoYimI645lJqADuRIcDMcEQJqqySA84g6P8cSJlScKnD0MQYsstr-JguAALTLs8-oXqy5HQCIRhMjwIicsAyxkVwkEensM4GEIIAkKQowdoGeChhAr7vlgkZjLCxKlkmKZpq88yZjS2algWRZ5pqsHvppUlQAAPlAOAYNKJawIgqDoNg+CEHJ5aqFWey1qUFRVDUzZ9m2dwmZ2TarpFA5tJsPRQH0AxDCM4wedOhl6OJj4-EuMUrr2raJdFHjZluO60vuqzrMlTonlgZ6asJOjQLKoVYLq+XQecL5vkkILXGsp5xPubjclJNTcE5LmWlgGK-isBorLNKxgGAWBuJURHEkYDIzBAdKQvMwFHttbiQD1gnLfCGEiLSHVBqEIiiHeQWHE+5zWfB1yIXwyGcOlUKYdh0B-fhB77SR2hkRRCRUYkHBLZxDFeSxbEeRcdicc43GLHxcQCUJIlMmJX2ehWUnvbJZAKTFSkqWpw2aaMznSg5r3zJMADaAC63PObSVl4bZuXCwtMRuRMaBMT5kB+XQAC+kS0IF9BFKNiyOnMAkJA1I48vCV2AqYJIQhlSKcV1DYRWVG4xXRMNgjt5y2vFjtJcbaVoWsWXINMgGDEKEm0KYCRvkaDQghMgYTOW6tdUETZUBM2y0zJoxpCrkxhMKhfZFkFBSXQKdGNolDucgme5XTow+GYCj50XWQl03fhcOXZSp4b6ceXXwYN04rieKMADkE+TK3wrtxQnfmN3tAV1AkgD7XWcgKMABC+iio6k8AIwAAxnyf0+t-Pi8KEAA)

Comment: Note the conversation in the PR referred to by @Lesiak in [their comment to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74461780/is-the-official-type-definition-for-json-stringify-wrong#comment131446720_74461780). There are a lot of trailing effects of changing the output type or adding overloads. I don't think it's as simple as this answer makes it appear. I do appreciate the idea though but making changes to TypeScript may be much more of an effort than you might think. I hear they appreciate PRs though :).

Comment: What if `T` is a function or bigint? It should also return `undefined`. See all the cases [here](https://evanhahn.com/when-stringify-doesnt-return-a-string/).

Comment: @caTS  yeah, it's easy to add more.  How far you go, not sure.  But even handling `undefined` is better than returning just `string`